# Remove some namespace prefixes with XLS

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

This is my XML

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:BAPI_PRODORD_GET_LIST>
         <ns:ORDER_NUMBER_RANGE>
            <ns:Item>
               <ns:SIGN>I</ns:SIGN>
               <ns:OPTION>EQ</ns:OPTION>
               <ns:LOW>150000033760</ns:LOW>
               <ns:HIGH>150000033765</ns:HIGH>
            </ns:Item>
         </ns:ORDER_NUMBER_RANGE>
         <ns:PLANPLANT_RANGE>
            <ns:Item>
               <ns:SIGN>I</ns:SIGN>
               <ns:OPTION>EQ</ns:OPTION>
               <ns:LOW>TM04</ns:LOW>
            </ns:Item>
         </ns:PLANPLANT_RANGE>
      </ns:BAPI_PRODORD_GET_LIST>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And i need this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions" 
            xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:BAPI_PRODORD_GET_LIST>
         <ORDER_NUMBER_RANGE>
            <item>
               <SIGN>I</SIGN>
               <OPTION>EQ</OPTION>
               <LOW>150000033760</LOW>
               <HIGH>150000033765</HIGH>
            </item>
         </ORDER_NUMBER_RANGE>
         <PLANPLANT_RANGE>
            <item>
               <SIGN>I</SIGN>
               <OPTION>EQ</OPTION>
               <LOW>TM04</LOW>
            </item>
         </PLANPLANT_RANGE>
      </ns:BAPI_PRODORD_GET_LIST>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I try with this XSLT, but remove all prefix and namespaces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | * | text()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Envelope/Body">
        <soapenv:Body><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></soapenv:Body>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This result is this:

```
<Envelope>
   <Header/>
   <Body>
      <BAPI_PRODORD_GET_LIST>
         <ORDER_NUMBER_RANGE>
            <Item>
               <SIGN>I</SIGN>
               <OPTION>EQ</OPTION>
               <LOW>150000033760</LOW>
               <HIGH>150000033765</HIGH>
            </Item>
         </ORDER_NUMBER_RANGE>
         <PLANPLANT_RANGE>
            <Item>
               <SIGN>I</SIGN>
               <OPTION>EQ</OPTION>
               <LOW>TM04</LOW>
            </Item>
         </PLANPLANT_RANGE>
      </BAPI_PRODORD_GET_LIST>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I need to remove all namespaces that are within `ns:BAPI_PRODORD_GET_LIST`

```
<ns:BAPI_PRODORD_GET_LIST>
<ns:ORDER_NUMBER_RANGE>
<ns:Item>
<ns:SIGN>I</ns:SIGN>
...
</ns:BAPI_PRODORD_GET_LIST>
```

The rest must remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

This stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ns:*//@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ns:*//*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions"
 xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:BAPI_PRODORD_GET_LIST>
         <ORDER_NUMBER_RANGE>
            <Item>
               <SIGN>I</SIGN>
               <OPTION>EQ</OPTION>
               <LOW>150000033760</LOW>
               <HIGH>150000033765</HIGH>
            </Item>
         </ORDER_NUMBER_RANGE>
         <PLANPLANT_RANGE>
            <Item>
               <SIGN>I</SIGN>
               <OPTION>EQ</OPTION>
               <LOW>TM04</LOW>
            </Item>
         </PLANPLANT_RANGE>
      </ns:BAPI_PRODORD_GET_LIST>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This use the "overwriting identity rule" pattern.